# erro Android Studio Flutter "The relevant error-causing widget was: Custom TextField Custom TextField"

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I'm creating an application in Flutter, and I'm in the registration screen part, and when I put the "Phone" field, this error appeared when running the app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5VNh.png)

this is the registration screen code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBGpM.png)

this is the custom text field screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget
{
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final IconData? data;
  final String? hintText;
  bool? isObsecre = true;
  bool? enabled = true;

  CustomTextField({
    this.controller,
    this.data,
    this.hintText,
    this.isObsecre,
    this.enabled,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TextFormField(
        enabled: enabled,
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: isObsecre!,
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            data,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          focusColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          hintText: hintText,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

could you help me to solve this problem?

I saw some videos to solve the problem but it didn't solve it

this is the tutorial I'm training to make the APP
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3-OWMFP9Q8&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlKgRigYdXvrTOawobNyqUS&index=5&ab_channel=CodingCafe

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your `CustomTextField` Widget somewhere with an explicit `null` value for `isObsecre`?
Because otherwise your provided code does not contain any errors.

Can you please include a stack trace of your error?